# display js variable to html using vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

how do i display firstname , lastname etc etc into data using vue.js
i have data in getData function so i have to display in data which is next to getData function. so how do i display firstname , lastname etc variable in data array, currently i am passing blank array to display, i have to pass value which is come through getData function

JS file

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

var getData = function(){
  axios.get('/api/getdataofmember')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data.data);
    var firstname = response.data.data.firstname;
    var lastname = response.data.data.lastname;
  });
}();



    const signupForm = new Vue({
        el: '#signup-form',
        data : {
            firstname : '',
            lastname :'',
            email : '',
            password : '',
            mobilenumber : '',
            date :''
        },
        methods: {
            processForm: function() {
        //attempt validating all
                this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
          if(result){
          var result1 = {
            'firstname' : this.firstname,
            'lastname' : this.lastname,
            'email' : this.email,
            'password' : this.password,
            'mobile_no' : this.mobilenumber,
            'dob' : moment(this.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
          }


            axios.post('/api/editmemberpro',result1)
            .then(function(response) {
              var result = response.data;
              var code=result.code;
              console.log(code);
              if(code==0)
              {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result.message;
              }
              else {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result.message;
              }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
                    }
                    this.firstname=this.lastname=this.email=this.password=this.mobilenumber=this.date="";
                    this.$validator.reset();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

html file

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>addmember</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
    <!-- include the VeeValidate library -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Notify vue about the VeeValidate plugin
     Vue.use(VeeValidate);
    </script>
        <style>
        .error {
          color: red;
        }
        .success{
          color: green;
        }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row main">
                  <div class="main-login main-center">
                  <h3>Edit Member Profile</h3>
                      <form id="signup-form" @submit.prevent="processForm">
                          <table>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <tr><td><label for="first name" >First Name : </label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="firstname" :class="{ 'form-control': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('firstname') }" v-model="firstname" v-validate="'required|alpha|min:2|max:20'"></td>
                              <td><span class="error" v-show="errors.has('firstname')">@{{ errors.first('firstname') }}</span></td></tr>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <tr><td><label for="last name" >Last Name : </label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="lastname"  :class="{ 'form-control': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('lastname') }" v-model="lastname" v-validate="'required|alpha|min:2|max:20'"></td>
                              <td><span class="error" v-show="errors.has('lastname')">@{{ errors.first('lastname') }}</span></td></tr>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <tr><td><label for="email">Email : </label></td>
                              <td><input type="email" :class="{ 'form-control': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('email') }" name="email"  v-model="email" v-validate="'required|email'" disabled></td>
                              <td><span class="error" v-show="errors.has('email')">@{{ errors.first('email') }}</span></td></tr>
                              </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <tr><td><label for="password">Password : </label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" :class="{ 'form-control': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('password') }" name="password"  v-model="password" v-validate="'required|min:6'"></td>
                              <td><span class="error" v-show="errors.has('password')">@{{ errors.first('password') }}</span></td></tr>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <tr><td><label for="Mobile Number">Mobile Number : </label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" :class="{ 'form-control': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('mobilenumber') }" name="mobilenumber"  v-model="mobilenumber" v-validate="{ required:true,numeric:true,min:10,max:10,regex:/^[6-9]\d{9}$/ }"></td>
                              <td><span class="error" v-show="errors.has('mobilenumber')">@{{ errors.first('mobilenumber') }}</span></td></tr>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <tr><td><label for="DOB">Date of Birth : </label></td>
                              <td><input type="date" :class="{ 'form-control': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('date') }" name="date"  v-model="date" v-validate="'required'"></td>
                              <td><span class="error" v-show="errors.has('date')">@{{ errors.first('date') }}</span></td></tr>
                          </div>
                        </table>
                          <div class="form-group ">
                              <button id="button" :disabled="errors.any()">Save</button>
                          </div>
                      </form>
                      <div id="result" class="success">  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </body>
    
           <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/memberprofile.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the result from Axios into a member variable (e.g. "result") and then use the mustache syntax to interpolate this variable into your template:

```
<div id="result" class="success">{{ result }}</div>

Vue.use(VeeValidate);

function getData(obj)
{
  axios.get('/api/getdataofmember')
  .then(function (response) 
  {
    console.log(response.data.data);
    obj.firstname = response.data.data.firstname;
    obj.lastname = response.data.data.lastname;
  });
}(signupForm);

const signupForm = new Vue({
    el: '#signup-form',
    data : {
        firstname : '',
        lastname :'',
        email : '',
        password : '',
        mobilenumber : '',
        result: '', // <----- here you store the result
        date :''
    },
    methods: {
        processForm: function() {
            //attempt validating all
            this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => 
            {
              if(result)
              {
                var result1 = {
        'firstname' : this.firstname,
        'lastname' : this.lastname,
        'email' : this.email,
        'password' : this.password,
        'mobile_no' : this.mobilenumber,
        'dob' : moment(this.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      }


        axios.post('/api/editmemberpro',result1)
        .then(function(response) {
          var result = response.data;
          var code=result.code;
          console.log(code);
          this.result = result.message; // <--- this command stores the result
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
                }
                this.firstname=this.lastname=this.email=this.password=this.mobilenumber=this.date="";
                this.$validator.reset();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i think you get it wrong...i have to only show the data which are come from getData function into textbox...rest are working fine

Comment: You probably have not noticed that `getData` requires an argument - your component instance where you want to store the data. It is also recommended that you implement this function as a method of the Vue component, or at least as a mixin (if you want to use it in several components).